# C# Byte[] to Url Friendly String

Tags: c#, base64, friendly-url

I'm working on a quick captcha generator for a simple site I'm putting together, and I'm hoping to pass an encrypted key in the url of the page. I could probably do this as a query string parameter easy enough, but I'm hoping not too (just because nothing else runs off the query string)...

My encryption code produces a byte[], which is then transformed using Convert.ToBase64String(byte[]) into a string. This string, however, is still not quite url friendly, as it can contain things like '/' and '='. Does anyone know of a better function in the .NET framework to convert a byte array to a url friendly string?

I know all about System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode() and its equivalents, however, they only work properly with query string parameters. If I url encode an '=' inside of the path, my web server brings back a 400 Bad Request error.

Anyways, not a critical issue, but hoping someone can give me a nice solution

**EDIT: Just to be absolutely sure exactly what I'm doing with the string, I figured I would supply a little more information.

The byte[] that results from my encryption algorithm should be fed through some sort of algorithm to make it into a url friendly string. After this, it becomes the content of an XElement, which is then used as the source document for an XSLT transformation, and is used as a part of the href attribute for an anchor. I don't believe the xslt transformation is causing the issues, since what is coming through on the path appears to be an encoded query string parameter, but causes the HTTP 400

I've also tried HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode() on a base64 string, but that doesn't seem to do the trick either (I still end up with '/'s in my url)**

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You're looking for `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` and `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode`, in `System.Web`.

They encode in base64, replacing the potentially dangerous '+' and '/' chars with '-' and '_' instead.

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode.aspx)

Comment: +1: Base64 is a more compact encoding than just using the hex digits from `BitConverter.ToString`.

Comment: Worked like a charm... Wicked (little known) function there... Thanks man

Comment: @LorenVS - sure. I didn't know it was there either, until we stumbled on it at work and replaced our own implementation with it.

Comment: Awesome! Fixed an issue I was having with Convert.ToBase64String and Convert.FromBase64String when transmitted in URL.

Comment: How annoying it is that Microsoft chose to place this in the `System.Web` assembly. Sigh.

Comment: @AsbjørnUlsberg, Kind of agree but does make sense since it is a domain specific version.  I can imagine other versions to deal with other issues, e.g.  User input: so avoid ['0', 'i' and 'l'].  I think it would be handy if ToBase64String() would take a parameter allowing for a custom set of characters.

Comment: **Use with caution** as UrlTokenEncode  adds a number at the end which indicates the number of = signs that were removed. See a possible solution here [link](https://codeday.me/en/qa/20190316/14910.html)

Answer (score 5):

For ASP.NET Core 6.0+ use [Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.WebEncoders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.webencoders):

```
byte[] bytes = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(64);

string encoded = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(bytes);
byte[] decoded = WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(encoded);
```

Comment: This is the correct solution , do not use other decoder

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [System.BitConverter.ToString(myByteArray)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx)

Handy for one way encoding for things like hashes but as pointed out by ssg it's not very efficient. I wouldn't recommend it for large amounts of data.

Comment: I'm willing to go to Hex Encoding, if there is a function to reverse this operation...

Comment: For Reference, BitConverter.GetBytes() doesn't have an overload which takes a string

Comment: Found this url for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230303/bitconverter-tostring-in-reverse will just use this solution

Comment: You need to keep in mind that this is very inefficient for transferring binary data. Data grows 300% this way instead of 130% as in base64.

Comment: @ssg - actually it grows to twice its size, not 4 times its size (2 chars per byte)

Comment: @orip: That's right. I thought of the original form with hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` and similar are no longer available in .NET Core as of .NET 6.
The following method should provide an RFC4648§5-compliant base64 string based on a quick reading.

This code allocates at least four objects on the heap, so ultra-high performance use cases should tune it a bit and perhaps wait for .NET 7, which is expected to introduce a means to get the random bytes into a Span for stack allocation.

```
private string GetUrlSafeRandomBytes(int byteCount)
{
    var salt = new byte[byteCount];
    using var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
    rng.GetBytes(salt);
    var asBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(salt);
    var asUrlSafeString = asBase64.Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
    return asUrlSafeString;
}
```