# How to achieve Base64 URL safe encoding in C#?

Tags: c#, encoding, base64

I want to achieve Base64 URL safe encoding in C#. In Java, we have the common `Codec` library which gives me an URL safe encoded string. How can I achieve the same using C#?

```
byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("StringToEncode");
string returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
```

The above code converts it to Base64, but it pads `==`. Is there is way to achieve URL safe encoding?

Comment: Can't you just use `Url.Encode` on string in `BASE64`?

Comment: In which namespace Url class is present in c#?

Comment: Take a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx You need to reference `System.Web` assembly.

Comment: It's converting = into %3D. I dont want that.

Comment: So what you mean by `url safe`? `%3D` is url safe.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228701/code-for-decoding-encoding-a-modified-base64-url

Answer (score 257, accepted):

It is common to *simply swap alphabet* for use in urls, so that no %-encoding is necessary; only 3 of the 65 characters are problematic - `+`, `/` and `=`. the most common replacements are `-` in place of `+` and `_` in place of `/`. As for the padding: *just remove it* (the `=`); you can *infer* the amount of padding needed. At the other end: just reverse the process:

```
string returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes)
        .TrimEnd(padding).Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
```

with:

```
static readonly char[] padding = { '=' };
```

and to reverse:

```
string incoming = returnValue
    .Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+');
switch(returnValue.Length % 4) {
    case 2: incoming += "=="; break;
    case 3: incoming += "="; break;
}
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(incoming);
string originalText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

The interesting question, however, is: *is this the same approach that the "common codec library" uses?* It would certainly be a reasonable first thing to test - this is a pretty common approach.

Comment: In Common Codec they are using [0-9a-zA-Z_-] Character for url safe mode.

Comment: this is also mentioned in the wiki page for Base64 under URL applications. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: You also have this function 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886686/c-sharp-byte-to-url-friendly-string' which does all the hard work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc; I was trying to decode a string created by Java's `encodeBase64URLSafeString` and in the end the issue was the missing padding on the end of the string that you solved with the `switch` statement!

Comment: Thanks for noting these characters.  When interfacing with different languages some functions do not return same results when encoding with encodeBASE64URL.  I am using PC Soft's WinDev v22 and it handles the problematic chars but the vendor I am working with what ever they are using does not... so you our HMAC_SHA_256 signatures where not matching and I found the issue in the encoding!

Comment: Just for search-findability... this is a great solution for decoding those pesky Google Gmail API bodies.

Comment: Why do we not need: case 1: incoming += "==="; break; ?

Comment: @alexdafranca because it will never have a length mod 4 of 1. 3x8 bits become 4x6 bits (and each 6 bits is one of 64 characters in the chosen alphabet), 0x8 bits is encoded as 0x6 bits without padding, 1x8 bits is encoded as 2x6 bits with `==` padding, 2x8 is encoded as 3x6 with `=` padding, 3x8 is encoded as 4x6 without padding and then it is aligned so it repeats. Nothing is ever encoded to 1x6 bits, so you never need `===` padding.

Answer (score 159):

You can use class `Base64UrlEncoder` from namespace `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`.

```
const string StringToEncode = "He=llo+Wo/rld";

var encodedStr = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(StringToEncode);
var decodedStr = Base64UrlEncoder.Decode(encodedStr);

if (decodedStr == StringToEncode)
    Console.WriteLine("It works!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Dangit!");
```

`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` is a NuGet package that has to be downloaded.

Comment: This is much cleaner than the accepted answer. Any downside ?

Comment: I'm assuming by the name that this isn't cross platform. Is that the case?

Comment: @BrandonS. Can confirm that it is cross platform.  Generating url encoded base 64 string encoded signature that is handled correctly on google GKE

Answer (score 53):

Another option, if you are using ASP.NET Core, would be to use [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.webencoders.base64urlencode).

If you are not using ASP.NET Core, [the `WebEncoders` source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Shared/WebEncoders/WebEncoders.cs) is available under the [Apache 2.0 License](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/LICENSE.txt).

Answer (score 12):

Based off the answers here with some performance improvements, we've published a very easy to use [url-safe base64 implementation to NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UrlBase64/) with the source code [available on GitHub](https://github.com/neosmart/UrlBase64/) (MIT licensed).

Usage is as easy as

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Foo");
var encoded = UrlBase64.Encode(bytes);
var decoded = UrlBase64.Decode(encoded);
```

Comment: Amazing thank you.  Out of interest why have you opted for `"string".Replace` for the `encode` method, but a loop with manual replaces for the `decode`?

Comment: @ᴍᴀᴛᴛʙᴀᴋᴇʀ I need to revisit it and run some benchmarks, but it's because we add to the latter so it's represented by a growable list of characters instead of an immutable string.

Comment: Another class with return type = string instead : https://github.com/vndevpro/architecture-common/blob/master/GdNet.Common/Services/Base64SafeEncoder.cs

Answer (score 9):

To get an URL-safe base64-like encoding, but not "base64url" according to RFC4648, use `System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(bytes)` to encode, and 
`System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(bytes)` to decode.

Comment: This doesn't provide a standards conform URL-safe Base64 encoding according to RFC4648. See also [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732145/c-base64url-according-to-rfc4648). **Use with caution.**

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution:
(with no padding)

```
private static string Base64UrlEncode(string input) {
    var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    // Special "url-safe" base64 encode.
    return Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes)
      .Replace('+', '-') // replace URL unsafe characters with safe ones
      .Replace('/', '_') // replace URL unsafe characters with safe ones
      .Replace("=", ""); // no padding
  }
```

Credit goes to: [Tholle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30246618/592651)

Answer (score 2):

```
    public string Decode(string str)
    {
       byte[] decbuff = Convert.FromBase64String(str.Replace(",", "=").Replace("-", "+").Replace("/", "_"));
       return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decbuff);
    }
    
    public string Encode(string input)
    {
        byte[] encbuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input ?? "");
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encbuff).Replace("=", ",").Replace("+", "-").Replace("_", "/");
    }
```

This is the way to do it to align with JavaScript!

Comment: Just based on the other answers, have you got that last `Replace` right? The other answers have `.Replace("/", "_")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method to decode an url-safe base64 was encode by same way with Marc. I just don't get why `4-length%4` worked(it does).

As follows, only the origin's bit length are common multiple of 6 and 8, base64 do not append "=" to result.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8|1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8|1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6|1 2 3 4 5 6|1 2 3 4 5 6|1 2 3 4 5 6
                "=="            "="
```

So we can do it conversely, if result's bit length can't divisible by 8, it has been appended:

```
base64String = base64String.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/");
var base64 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64String);
var padding = base64.Length * 3 % 4;//(base64.Length*6 % 8)/2
if (padding != 0)
{
    base64String = base64String.PadRight(base64String.Length + padding, '=');
}
return Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
```

Answer (score 0):

Karanvir Kang's answer is a good one and I voted for it. However, it does leave an odd character on the end of the string (indicating the number of padding characters removed). Here is my solution.

```
var bytesToEncode = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("StringToEncode"); 
var bytesEncodedPadded = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(bytesToEncode);
var objectIdBase64 = bytesEncodedPadded.Substring(0, bytesEncodedPadded.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score -2):

Using Microsoft cryptographic engine in UWP.

```
uint length = 32;

IBuffer buffer = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(length);
string base64Str = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(buffer)
                   // ensure url safe
                   .TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');

return base64Str;
```