# c# JWT load ES256 PEM file into CngKey (jose-jwt)

Tags: c#, jwt

As a quick overview I am attempting to generate a ES256 algorithm -JWT token via C# using the https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt library.

As the directions state:

> ES256, ES384, ES256 ECDSA signatures requires CngKey (usually private)
>   elliptic curve key of corresponding length. Normally existing CngKey
>   loaded via CngKey.Open(..) method from Key Storage Provider. But if
>   you want to use raw key material (x,y) and d, jose-jwt provides
>   convenient helper EccKey.New(x,y,d).

The CngKey.Open() states it opens an existing key, but by the sounds of it I should be using the CngKey.Import() instead? When I attempt to call the CngKey.Import() it returns the following error:

> The parameter is incorrect.

Basically what I am asking is what is the simplest way to convert an existing PEM file into the CngKey object which is required for the Jose.JWT.Encode() function? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Below is my code(for security purposed that is not the real private key):

```
public string GenerateToken(int contactID, Database _db)
        {
            var contact = GetContact(contactID, _db);
            var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {"broker", 1},
                {"contact_id", contact.id},
                {"name", contact.fname + " " + contact.lname + ""},
                {"iss", "www.somewhere.com"},
                {"iat", (DateTime.Now - UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds},
                {"nbf", (DateTime.Now - UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds},
                {"exp", (DateTime.Now.AddDays(30) - UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds}
            };    

            string privateKey =
            "MHcCAQEffEIIIHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHffHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHoGgCCqGSM49" +
            "AwEHhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhI+pRkAxAb13" +
            "77vz2Yjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjw==";
            byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);

            CngKey cng = CngKey.Import(b, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob);
            string token = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, cng, JwsAlgorithm.ES256);
            return token;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with `jose-jwt` and got it working using my own implementation of `GetECDsaPrivateKey()`. Note that your project should target **.NET 4.6.1**. Please follow the steps below:

1.Generate a **p12** `X509Certificate2` using **openssl**

```
> openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey > private-key.pem
> openssl ec -in private-key.pem -pubout -out public-key.pem
> openssl req -new -key private-key.pem -x509 -nodes -days 365 -out public.cer
> winpty openssl pkcs12 -export -in public.cer -inkey private-key.pem -out publiccert.p12
```

2.Generate a **JWT** by reading **private key** from above generated certificate:

```
var claims = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "sub", "mr.x@contoso.com" },
    { "exp", 1300819380 }
};

var certificate = new X509Certificate2("publiccert.p12", "passcode");
string token = SignJWTWithCert(certificate, claims);

private static string SignJWTWithCert(X509Certificate2 cert, object claims)
{
        var header = new { alg = "ES256", typ = "JWT" };
        byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(header, Formatting.None));
        byte[] claimsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(claims, Formatting.None));

        using (ECDsa ecdsa = cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey())
        {
            if (ecdsa == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Cert must have an ECDSA private key", nameof(cert));

            var payload = Base64UrlEncode(headerBytes) + "." + Base64UrlEncode(claimsBytes);
            var signature = ecdsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
            return payload + "." + Base64UrlEncode(signature);
        }
}
```

Comment: This seems really helpful, assuming that it works, but is it possible to share what `Base64UrlEncode()` does exactly? First encodes to base64 and then url-encodes? Or the opposite?

Comment: Also, where do you get the exponent (dictionary key `exp` above) from? Is there a way to find it using the generated certificate?

Comment: `exp` is exipry (a unix timestamp). You can generate it using the programming of your choice And For `Base64UrlEncode()`, you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30246618

Comment: A slick way to import an openssl generated PEM key into a .NET environment - exactly what I needed.