# How can I read the whole message using Gmail API

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I need all the text in the body for incoming email.

I tried:

```
var mesage = GetMessage(service, "me", 1);
Console.WriteLine(mesage.Snippet);

public static Message GetMessage(GmailService service, String userId, String messageId)
{
    try
    {
        return service.Users.Messages.Get(userId, messageId).Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
    }

    return null;
}
```

But I am getting just snippet as shown in the screenshot.

Incoming mail to me:
[image]
Result:

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you printing? Your method seems to correctly return a Message object, but without knowing what you are doing afterwards, we can't help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Gmail_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1Message.html), `Message.Snippet` only returns a short part of the message text. You should instead use `Message.Raw`, or more appropriately, `Message.Payload.Body`?

```
var message = GetMessage(service, "me", 1);
Console.WriteLine(message.Raw);
Console.WriteLine(message.Payload.Body.Data);
```

You should try both out and see what works best for what you're trying to do.
To get `message.Raw` you need to pass a parameter, as stated in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Gmail_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1Message.html#a6fcadc2c456c5c0d7d0e90fa53b639b0):

> Returned in messages.get and drafts.get responses when the format=RAW parameter is supplied.

If none of those things work, you could try iterating over the parts of the message to find your data:

```
foreach (var part in message.Payload.Parts)
{
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(part.Body.Data);
    string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    Console.WriteLine(decodedString);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried them. But;
Console.WriteLine(message.Raw); Result: Null

Console.WriteLine(message.Payload.Body); Result: Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.MessagePartBody

Comment: See my edit; try `Payload.Body.Data` which is a string (I looked at the docs a bit too briefly)

Comment: Payload.Body.Data result Null

Comment: Seems like the payload can be made up of different parts... What if you try `message.Payload.Parts[0].Body.Data`? You should ideally iterate over all  payload parts to find your data.

Comment: yes i have 2 parts. message.Payload.Parts[0].Body.Data I got results. But how it is to base64url decode.

Comment: Easy! see my edit. Make sure you have the right Usings.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26354677/235648) for decoding a base64 url encoded string, this is how I used to fetch the most likely message part that contains the text or html that the user sees:

```cs
string? GetMessageBodyText(Message message) {
    var part = message.Payload;

    while (part is not null) {
        var mimeType = part.MimeType;

        if (mimeType is "text/plain" or "text/html") {
            return DecodeBase64UrlString(part.Body.Data);
        }

        part = part.Parts?.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return null;
}

string DecodeBase64UrlString(string encoded) {
    var dec = encoded.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/");
    var data = Convert.FromBase64String(dec);
    var decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    return decodedString;
}
```