# Passing a url encoded byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, urlencode

I need to pass a byte array via a URL. So I am encoding it with the `UrlEncode` Method like this:

```
string ergebnis = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(array);
```

The result is the following string: `%00%00%00%00%00%25%b8j`

Now when I pass this string in a URL like this `http://localhost:51980/api/Insects?Version=%00%00%00%00%00%25%b8j`

This is my `Get` function:

```
        public List<TaxonDiagnosis> Get([FromUri] string version)
        {
            List<TaxonDiagnosis> result = new List<TaxonDiagnosis>();

            result = db.TaxonDiagnosis.ToList();

            byte[] array = HttpUtility.UrlDecodeToBytes(version);

            if (version != null)
                result = db.GetTaxonDiagnosis(array).ToList();

            return result;
        }
```

The problem is, `version`'s value isn't `%00%00%00%00%00%25%b8j`. Instead it is this `\0\0\0\0\0%�j`. This of course causes problems when I try to decode it into a `byte array` again.

How can I pass the correct string in the Url?

Comment: I suggest you use base64 encode the data with a URL-safe base64 decodabet.

Comment: Well I'd start off by doing some research. Just searching on SO found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353710/how-to-achieve-base64-url-safe-encoding-in-c

Comment: It seems that `version` is already url-decoded. But it's kinda complicated to get bytes out of a string, due to encodings (as you can see %25%b8 ends up as a unicode character in your string). I don't have detailed knowledge about those web services...isn't it possible to change the method's argument from `string version` to `byte[] array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Jon Skeet, I encoded the arraywith a URL-safe base64 decodabet like in this post: [How to achieve Base64 URL safe encoding in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353710/how-to-achieve-base64-url-safe-encoding-in-c)