# What is the difference between Convert.ToBase64String(byte[]) and HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(byte[])?

Tags: c#, base64, system.web

I'm trying to remove a dependence on `System.Web.dll` from a Web API project, but have stumbled on a call to [`HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(byte[] input)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode(v=vs.110).aspx) (and its corresponding decode method) that I don't know what to replace with to ensure backwards compatibility. The documentation says that this method

> Encodes a byte array into its equivalent string representation using base 64 digits, which is usable for transmission on the URL.

I tried substituting with [`Convert.ToBase64String(byte[] input)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) (and its corresponding decode method), which is very similarly described in the docs:

> Converts an array of 8-bit unsigned integers to its equivalent string representation that is encoded with base-64 digits.

However, they don't seem to be entirely equivalent; when using `Convert.FromBase64String(string input)` to decode a string encoded with `HttpServerUtility`, I get an exception stating

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

**What is the difference between these two conversion utilities? What's the correct way to remove this dependence on `System.Web.HttpServerUtility`?**

---

Some users have suggested that this is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353710), but I disagree. That question is about base-64-encoding a string in a url-safe manner *in general*, but I need to reproduce the *exact behavior* of `HttpServerUtility` but without a dependency on `System.Web`.

Comment: You could take a look at the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/httpserverutility.cs,86c172090435d2fa,references), might shed some light.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to achieve Base64 URL safe encoding in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353710/how-to-achieve-base64-url-safe-encoding-in-c)

Answer (score 16):

I took DGibbs on their word and [Used](http://adastraerrans.com/archivos/use-the-source-luke.png) the [Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/httpserverutility.cs,86c172090435d2fa). It turns out the following happens in the `HttpServerUtility` methods:

#### Encoding to Base64

1. Use `System.Convert` to convert the input to Base64.
2. Replace `+` by `-` and `/` by `_`. Example: `Foo+bar/===` becomes `Foo-bar_===`.
3. Replace any number of `=` at the end of the string, with an integer denoting how many they were. Example: `Foo-bar_===` becomes `Foo-bar_3`.

#### Decoding from Base64

1. Replace the digit at the end of the string by the same number of `=` signs. Example: `Foo-bar_3` becomes `Foo-bar_===`.
2. Replace `-` by `+` and `_` by `/`. Example: `Foo-bar_===` becomes `Foo+bar/===`.
3. Use `System.Convert` to decode the preprocessed input from Base64.

Comment: It should also be noted that the number at the end is required - i.e. no `=` signs will append `0` to the output/interpreted from the input.

Answer (score 4):

`HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(byte[] input)` will encode a URL safe Base64 string. In Base64 +, / and = characters are valid, but they are not URL safe, this method will replace these characters whereas the `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[] input)` will not. You can probably drop the reference and do it yourself.

Usually, '+' is replaced with '-' and '/' with '_' padding '=' is just removed.

Accepted answer here gives a code example: [How to achieve Base64 URL safe encoding in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353710/how-to-achieve-base64-url-safe-encoding-in-c)

Comment: This is actually not entirely correct. Padding `=` aren't *removed*, they're *replaced with an integer denoting their count*. In other words, `blah==` becomes `blah2`, not `blah`. (Found this out from looking at the source).