# How to deserialize string with inconsistent base64 encoding using newtonsoft json

Tags: c#, json, serialization, base64

I have a string returned from a web service containing a JSON string.
Some of the properties in the string are base 64 encoded. Trouble is they are not base64 encoded in a consistent way. As per  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history there is some variation in base64 encoding. I know what I'm expecting, and I need to preprocess a certain property value before decoding an deserializing it. I'm looking for the hooks in `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` or `JsonSerializerSettings` in order to do that.

To be clear, the json I need to deserialize includes multiple properties with base 64 encoding. Some have / + and padding, others have _ - and no padding. The latter causes an exception:

> "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters. "

Comment: Those weird looking encodings are base-64 url encoded string. a modification to base-64 to allow for safe transfer in urls. Check the  [**URL applications**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications) section of the wiki you linked

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26354677/782754

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom JsonConverter and introduced it via JsonSerializerSettings
Thanks
Martin