# How to use RNGCryptoServiceProvider generated string in url/query string

Tags: cryptography, url-encoding, rngcryptoserviceprovider

**NOTE**: I have already solved the problem mentioned in this post. 
After doing lot of google I couldn't find right solution. As now I know the answer. I thought this post will save other developer's time trying to solve same.

**Problem**:

I wanted to Generate Cryptographic random string and send that as part of url to user. With Base64 string you will likely get **Error:**

> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that
>   contains a double escape sequence

or it will not find your Route.

**So either you hack/workaround and find/replace escape chars on Base64 String or use this solution.**

This is how my original code look like.

```
  public string GenerateRandomString()
  {
     var randomBytes = GenerateRandomBytes(512);

     var randomString = Convert.ToBase64String(randomBytes);

     return randomString;
  }

  private byte[] GenerateRandomBytes(int keyBitLength)
  {
     using (var provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
     {
        var lengthInByte = keyBitLength / 8;
        var randomNumber = new byte[lengthInByte];
        provider.GetBytes(randomNumber);

        return randomNumber;
     }
  }
```

**Solution** is UrlTokenEncode. Added new method to convert random bytes to Url Encoded Token.

```
public string GenerateRandomStringToken()
{
    var randomBytes = GenerateRandomBytes(512);
    return HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(randomBytes);
}

private byte[] GenerateRandomBytes(int keyBitLength)
{
   using (var provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
   {
      var lengthInByte = keyBitLength / 8;
      var randomNumber = new byte[lengthInByte];
      provider.GetBytes(randomNumber);

      return randomNumber;
   }
}
```

Comment: Use the Base64 version then trivially make it URL safe as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353710/how-to-achieve-base64-url-safe-encoding-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In above question Solution is also provided.