# Encrypt and decrypt parameter passed in on query string

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I'm using (or attempting to!) the code for encrypting/decrypting a string found in this post [Encrypting & Decrypting a String in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp).

If I call the functions directly, i.e.

```
StringHelper sHelp = new StringHelper();

var encryptMe = sHelp.EncryptString("comahony@centlaw.com", "myPassphrase");
```

Returns /sx3sL4DE7sM2klGKN3V+CQKdP02ZxbVxANjDh2yfGo=  which is perfect

and if I then call

```
var decryptMe = sHelp.DecryptString(encryptMe, "myPassphrase");
```

Returns comahony@centlaw.com which again is what I'm after.

But if I pass the encrypted string on parameter on the querystring. i.e.

http://localhost:12345/sso?c=/sx3sL4DE7sM2klGKN3V+CQKdP02ZxbVxANjDh2yfGo=

and call the decryption function using:

```
var decryptMe = sHelp.DecryptString(Request.QueryString["c"].ToString(), "myPassphrase");
```

I'm getting the error of "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."

From digging around on the net it appears to be something to do with the parameter needing to be URLEncoded but try as I might I just can't get past this error.

Could something shed some light please?

Thanks,
C

Comment: Have you debugged to see the value of `Request.QueryString["c"].ToString()`? maybe its just plain wrong. I can't help you if I don't know the input

Comment: Base64 can contain + and / characters which can have special meaning when present in a query string you should pre/post substitute them with other characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to achieve Base64 URL safe encoding in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353710/how-to-achieve-base64-url-safe-encoding-in-c)

Comment: `+` has a special meaning in URLs. That's why there are URL specific [variants of Base 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table)

Comment: Right right, so basically I need encrypt the string and replace the special characters (/ +) before it's appended to the QS and then replace the special characters before de-encrypting it.

Comment: "Replace", use HttpUtility.UrlEncode/UrlDecode, but yes, just don't handroll the replacement, use the built in methods for this.