# How to fix encoded URL to bind parameters correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes, modelbinders

I'm using a **Bank E-Payment webservice** and set the `redirectURL` into `http://Example.com/EPaymentResultCallback?Param1=0&Param2=1`
when the bank finish it's job, browser redirects to preceding url.
But the problem is: Bank webservice has changed my url into `http://Example.com/EPaymentResultCallback?Param1=0&amp;Param2=1` (noticing the extra `&amp;`).
In fact my innocent url encoded and therefore **Param2 will be lost**.
I cannot change the websercive obviously. but interested to know if there is a way to resolve the second url parameter (`Param2`) on my website?

For more general explanation: 'mywebsite' calls a webservice and redirected to a whole new website. after 'new website' done, browser redirects to the given URL (in fact 'mywebsite/somesubUrl/param1&param2') but parameter separator (**&**) changed into (`&amp;`) so the second parameter (param2) won't delivered correctly to the action method and an exception raise, pointing that the second input parameter in the action method could not be null.

Actually i`m looking for a built-in solution to read encrypted url. that would be the best. but any other idea is welcomed.

Comment: I'd change the query parameters into an encoded/encrypted string or the like. If, for example, you encrypt your `Param1=0&Param2=1` to `yourencryptedstring12345`,  then make the redirect URL `EPaymentResultCallback?action=yourencryptedstring`, then you can decrypt the action parameter `yourencryptedstring12345` into `Param1=0&Param2=1` and you're set

Comment: @Milanzorg Thats a good idea but not the best. actually i`m looking for a built-in solution to read encrypted url.

Comment: something like [base64-url-safe-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353710/how-to-achieve-base64-url-safe-encoding-in-c) and [encode-url-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript?rq=1)?