# Decrypt Python cryptography fernet token in C#

Tags: c#, python, cryptography

I have written an encryption function in Python, which works fine.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
def Encryptor(password):
    key = b'MAKV2SPBNI99212'
    cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
    ciphered_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(password)
    print(ciphered_text)
```

This works fine

For example

```
EncryptDecrypt.Encryptor(b"HellowWorld")
```

returns the below output

b'gAAAAABbIWGJt5gEZoCezKoWpMNxNk_SNTGoe9KlUoquktNbpo1JFL87PxZAi-CtCF2eXHfgZ0F5iPCV-qn2wRhheWfWG6eHJw=='

How do I decrypt this in C#. I do not want to use Pycrypto in Python

Here is the code I am trying in C# but it is not working as the IV needs to be 16 bytes

```
public static string Decrypt()
{
    byte[] someone = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("gAAAAABbIWGJt5gEZoCezKoWpMNxNk_SNTGoe9KlUoquktNbpo1JFL87PxZAi-CtCF2eXHfgZ0F5iPCV-qn2wRhheWfWG6eHJw==");        
    byte[] keybytes = Convert.FromBase64String("MAKV2SPBNI99212");
    RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keybytes, someone);
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("gAAAAABbIWGJt5gEZoCezKoWpMNxNk_SNTGoe9KlUoquktNbpo1JFL87PxZAi-CtCF2eXHfgZ0F5iPCV-qn2wRhheWfWG6eHJw==");
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
    int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
    memoryStream.Close();
    cryptoStream.Close();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);

}
```

Comment: instead of writing `*put some data here*` post a real example so that people can test the code.

Comment: `-` and `_` are not valid chars for base64 encoding

Comment: @Eser that is what I am trying to figure out. Is there another way to decrypt the bytestream which includes - and _ ?

Comment: Your (*Python*) code sample **does not work**, because the key that you pass to `Fernet` constructor (`cipher_suite = Fernet(key)`) is incorrect: `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with your key. It is too much short. Written some code for Fernet encryption/decryption (it is very basic, not stream-based), tested with a test vector found [at a javascript implementation of Fernet](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/generate.json). The specification of the Fernet algorithm can be found [here](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md). Note that you can't use directly `Convert.FromBase64String`, because the format used by Fernet is Base64 url-safe. I've put a small method to convert from it.

```
public static class SimpleFernet
{
    // Fernet: from https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md

    // return value is base64 url encoded
    // trimEnd is to force trimming of return value
    public static string EncryptFernet(byte[] key, byte[] data, DateTime? timestamp = null, byte[] iv = null, bool trimEnd = false)
    {
        // Fernet: from https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md

        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        }

        if (key.Length != 32)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(key));
        }

        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));
        }

        if (iv != null && iv.Length != 16)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(iv));
        }

        if (timestamp == null)
        {
            timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        byte[] result = new byte[57 + ((data.Length + 16) / 16 * 16)];

        result[0] = 0x80;

        {
            // BigEndian to LittleEndian
            long timestamp2 = new DateTimeOffset(timestamp.Value).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
            timestamp2 = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(timestamp2);
            byte[] timestamp3 = BitConverter.GetBytes(timestamp2);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(timestamp3, 0, result, 1, timestamp3.Length);
        }

        using (var aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            byte[] encryptionKey = new byte[16];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(key, 16, encryptionKey, 0, 16);

            aes.Key = encryptionKey;

            if (iv != null)
            {
                aes.IV = iv;
            }
            else
            {
                aes.GenerateIV();
            }

            Buffer.BlockCopy(aes.IV, 0, result, 9, 16);

            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                byte[] encrypted = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(encrypted, 0, result, 25, encrypted.Length);
            }
        }

        byte[] signingKey = new byte[16];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(key, 0, signingKey, 0, 16);

        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(signingKey))
        {
            hmac.TransformFinalBlock(result, 0, result.Length - 32);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(hmac.Hash, 0, result, result.Length - 32, 32);
        }

        return Base64UrlEncode(result, trimEnd);
    }

    // Token is base64 url encoded
    public static byte[] DecryptFernet(byte[] key, string token, out DateTime timestamp)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        }

        if (key.Length != 32)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(key));
        }

        if (token == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(token));
        }

        byte[] token2 = Base64UrlDecode(token);

        if (token2.Length < 57)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(token));
        }

        byte version = token2[0];

        if (version != 0x80)
        {
            throw new Exception("version");
        }

        // Check the hmac
        {
            byte[] signingKey = new byte[16];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(key, 0, signingKey, 0, 16);

            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(signingKey))
            {
                hmac.TransformFinalBlock(token2, 0, token2.Length - 32);
                byte[] hash2 = hmac.Hash;

                IEnumerable<byte> hash = token2.Skip(token2.Length - 32).Take(32);

                if (!hash.SequenceEqual(hash2))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Wrong HMAC!");
                }
            }
        }

        {
            // BigEndian to LittleEndian
            long timestamp2 = BitConverter.ToInt64(token2, 1);
            timestamp2 = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(timestamp2);

            timestamp = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(timestamp2).UtcDateTime;
        }

        byte[] decrypted;

        using (var aes = new AesManaged())
        {
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            byte[] encryptionKey = new byte[16];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(key, 16, encryptionKey, 0, 16);
            aes.Key = encryptionKey;

            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(token2, 9, iv, 0, 16);
            aes.IV = iv;

            using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor())
            {
                const int startCipherText = 25;
                int cipherTextLength = token2.Length - 32 - 25;
                decrypted = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(token2, startCipherText, cipherTextLength);
            }
        }

        return decrypted;
    }

    public static string Base64UrlEncode(byte[] bytes, bool trimEnd = false)
    {
        int length = (bytes.Length + 2) / 3 * 4; ;
        var chars = new char[length];
        Convert.ToBase64CharArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, chars, 0);

        int trimmedLength = length;

        if (trimEnd)
        {
            switch (bytes.Length % 3)
            {
                case 1:
                    trimmedLength -= 2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    trimmedLength -= 1;
                    break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < trimmedLength; i++)
        {
            switch (chars[i])
            {
                case '/':
                    chars[i] = '_';
                    break;
                case '+':
                    chars[i] = '-';
                    break;
            }
        }

        string result = new string(chars, 0, trimmedLength);
        return result;
    }

    public static byte[] Base64UrlDecode(string s)
    {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/26354677/613130
        // But totally rewritten :-)

        char[] chars;

        switch (s.Length % 4)
        {
            case 2:
                chars = new char[s.Length + 2];
                chars[chars.Length - 2] = '=';
                chars[chars.Length - 1] = '=';
                break;
            case 3:
                chars = new char[s.Length + 1];
                chars[chars.Length - 1] = '=';
                break;
            default:
                chars = new char[s.Length];
                break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (s[i])
            {
                case '_':
                    chars[i] = '/';
                    break;
                case '-':
                    chars[i] = '+';
                    break;
                default:
                    chars[i] = s[i];
                    break;
            }
        }

        byte[] result = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(chars, 0, chars.Length);
        return result;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Test vector taken from https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/generate.json
    byte[] key = Base64UrlDecode("cw_0x689RpI-jtRR7oE8h_eQsKImvJapLeSbXpwF4e4=");
    string token = "gAAAAAAdwJ6wAAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODy021cpGVWKZ_eEwCGM4BLLF_5CV9dOPmrhuVUPgJobwOz7JcbmrR64jVmpU4IwqDA==";
    DateTime timestamp;
    string result = DecryptFernet(key, token, out timestamp);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is close works with the token you provided. However when I use the token I got from the encrypt method in Python, it does not work. 
Error in the line if (!hash.SequenceEqual(hash2)). 
Also for decrypting the token you provided,I am getting the error cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken in python

Comment: Can you try with this vector gAAAAABbIXmNE6v5uaUYNxbQIFuHLokphd7OzAg-dekcC3-XlllcwWly3HJvUlPAMBWsgCLWiKBMGVReeRtXLFoMS-ZVLPwAlw==

Comment: @AlexT The vector I gave works correctly: https://ideone.com/RuLPLB . Response `hello`

Comment: Yes it is working for me to with the vector you provided. However not with the vector generated by the encrypt method in python. Please assist me

Comment: @AlexT I need a password and a vector. And try them in the ideone I linked to show that they really work.

Comment: @AlexT You have to use python 3 in ideone, because the python 2.6 of ideone isn't complete.

Comment: @alexT Here using python 2.7: https://repl.it/repls/HeavenlyWealthyMysql

Comment: I rewrote my encrypt function in python!!! The same code!!!! used the token... and magically works!!!!!!!!!