# What does office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId do?

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, office365api

I must convert an EWSId (ItemId) to a RestId from within Java, so i cannot use office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId.

Any idea what this method does internally so i can rewrite it in Java?

Answer (score 1):

The RESTId's are just a URL safe version of the EWSId which is Base64 but not URL safe. That said in Beta there is an action in the Graph that can be used to convert Id's which is always going to be the safest approach https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/api/user-translateexchangeids.md

Comment: Thank You. Unfortunately this does not seem to work for EWS FolderIds. Is there a way to convert EWS FolderIds?

Comment: What have you tried ? the simplest way of making it URL safe would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353710/how-to-achieve-base64-url-safe-encoding-in-c using replace for the unsafe characters.