# IDataProtector Unprotect: The input is not a valid Base-64 string

Tags: token, data-protection, blazor-server-side

I had problems with Identity ConfirmEmailAsync and always it returns Invalid Token. So I write a custom TokenProvider. at one side I have this Code:

```
//string confirmationToken = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
string confirmationToken = await tokenProvider.GenerateAsyncEmail("mzpurposes", userManager, user);

string confirmationLink =
            $"{httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Host}" +
            $"/account/confirmemail/{System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(user.Id)}" +
            $"/{System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(confirmationToken)}";
```

and at the other side in the ConfirmEmail page that Recieves UserID and Token as input Route parameters:

```
//IdentityResult result = await userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Token));
    bool result =
        await tokenProvider.ValidateAsyncEmail("mzpurposes", System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Token), userManager, user);
    if (result)   //.Succeeded)
    {
        Model = new UserConfirmModel() { Success = true };
    }
    else
    {
        Model = new UserConfirmModel() { Success = false };
    }
```

In the custom TokenProvider at the end of the method that creates the token I have:

```
var protectedBytes = protector.Protect(ms.ToArray());
        return Convert.ToBase64String(protectedBytes);
```

and at the begining of Validate Method there is:

```
 var unprotectedData = protector.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(token));
```

every time I click the confirmation link and code reaches to this line I get this error:

**The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."}**

Why do I recieve this error when I convert the bytes at the end of the method GenerateAsyncEmail to base64string?
also in the startup class I have: services.AddDataProtection(); and I inject it to tokenprovider class.

I am Sure this is a bug in Blazor Serverside Component's input parameters.

Comment: it looks like you are passing something different in `FromBase64String` than what you get after `ToBase64String` i guess you don't need to `UrlDecode`

Comment: I tested removing it before, but it didn't work too. I finally created a 6 digit random number and passed it to ConfirmEmail page that solved my issue. But It is not as secure as a token, I spend days to solve this in Blazor serverside preview 6(it is working in blazor client side preview 5) and tried every scenario with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware of that you need to use an URL safe version of Base64 to avoid getting issues when you pass Base64 strings via querystrings

see
[How to achieve Base64 URL safe encoding in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353710/how-to-achieve-base64-url-safe-encoding-in-c)