# ES 512 jwt token verification

Tags: c#, jwt, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

I am trying to verify ES512 jwt token using public key which is in string format:

I am trying to imitate a sample written for ES256
which is something like this:

```
    // The code for ES256
    public static void VerifyES512Jwt(string token,string publicKey)
    {
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey);

        string[] parts = token.Split('.');

        string header = parts[0];
        string payload = parts[1];
        string signature = parts[2];

        var keyType = new byte[] { 0x45, 0x43, 0x53, 0x31 };
        var keyLength = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        var key = keyType.Concat(keyLength).Concat(publicKeyBytes.Skip(publicKeyBytes.Length - 64)).ToArray(); 
        CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Import(key, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
        
        // the purpose is to get ECDsaCng and verify the payload data
         ECDsaCng eCDsaCng = new ECDsaCng(cngKey);
        
        bool result = eCDsaCng.VerifyData(payload, signatureBytes); 
    }
```

I am trying to use this code for ES512 and got stuck on getting the key

```
        var keyType = new byte[] { 0x45, 0x43, 0x53, 0x31 };
        var keyLength = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
        var key = keyType.Concat(keyLength).Concat(publicKeyBytes.Skip(publicKeyBytes.Length - 64)).ToArray();
```

when used with the above it gives error in getting key:

```
CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Import(key, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
```

The public key and token I am using are as follows:
public key:

> MIGbMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAjA4GGAAQBgc4HZz+/fBbC7lmEww0AO3NK9wVZ
> PDZ0VEnsaUFLEYpTzb90nITtJUcPUbvOsdZIZ1Q8fnbquAYgxXL5UgHMoywAib47
> 6MkyyYgPk0BXZq3mq4zImTRNuaU9slj9TVJ3ScT3L1bXwVuPJDzpr5GOFpaj+WwM
> Al8G7CqwoJOsW7Kddns=

Token:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzUxMiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJPbmxpbmUgSldUIEJ1aWxkZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NjUwOTk2ODgsImV4cCI6MTU5ODE4OTg4NSwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozNTg4Iiwic3ViIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDM3NiIsImZpcnN0bmFtZSI6IkFydmluZCIsImxhc3RuYW1lIjoiS3VtYXIiLCJFbWFpbCI6ImFydmluZC5rdW1hckBzdHJlYW1hbWcuY29tIiwiSWQiOiIxMDEifQ.AVwAJeY44lKrnywnDs7CdUOu3gli2cGafSJ6iP3zT7lkZpd2QnL0k54aVmPVxAGuN5dDnzbYmMTdRl5u2QE92ccOAHrcf5yA2gsvhhAGuDAAeh6Io4VU7v5TOTvwWGRb-ubgdjUvagA_HSJOyeXvFR16_M_MzGfDnXfg02sj4y9VFjDr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ES512](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.1) uses ECDSA with P-521 and SHA-512.

A public key for P-521 ([secp521r1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf), chap. 2.6.1) has a size of `2 x 66 = 132` bytes in uncompressed form (front byte `0x04`). MS specifies the public key for P-521 with the value [`0x35534345`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/Interop/Windows/BCrypt/Interop.Blobs.cs).

The key must therefore be generated as follows:

```
var keyType = new byte[] { 0x45, 0x43, 0x53, 0x35 };
var keyLength = new byte[] { 0x42, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
var key = keyType.Concat(keyLength).Concat(publicKeyBytes.Skip(publicKeyBytes.Length - 132)).ToArray();
```

The data to be signed are header and payload (both Base64url encoded) including the separator (`.`). The signature is also Base64url encoded. The verification must therefore be performed as follows:

```
byte[] headerPayloadBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header + "." + payload);
byte[] signatureBytes = Base64UrlDecode(signature);
bool verified = eCDsaCng.VerifyData(headerPayloadBytes, signatureBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512);
```

`Base64UrlDecode` accomplishes the Base64url decoding, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26354677/9014097) for implementation details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Generating key worked well, however, eCDsaCng.VerifyData(headerPayloadBytes, signatureBytes);
did not work, Token otherwise is verified when i used

var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                IssuerSigningKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(pubKey)
            };

            SecurityToken stoken;
            var claims = securityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out stoken);

Comment: @ArvindKrmar - I can't reproduce your problem. Runs fine locally on my machine and also here on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lQosw1). Both codes seem functionally more or less identical to me. My code (or rather the code you posted in your question) validates more directly, while the code posted in your answer encapsulates the validation process in some JWT classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway. 
your suggestions have solved my problem and it was a great help.
 I'll again try to execute the code above

Comment: The code you suggested work a bit differently, I added this line 
eCDsaCng.HashAlgorithm =  CngAlgorithm.Sha512;

bool verified = eCDsaCng.VerifyData(headerPayloadBytes, signatureBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512);

for me
eCDsaCng.VerifyData(); does not have the third parameter. HashAlgorithmName.SHA512
When i add the algorithm in eCDsaCng, it works
This change might be because I am running it on Dot Net V 4.5 which is different from yours perhaps.

Comment: Yes, that's right. In .NET Framework 3.5 to 4.6, the [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsacng.verifydata?view=netframework-4.8#overloads) of `VerifyData` used by you must be applied. The [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.verifydata?view=netframework-4.8#overloads) used by me exists _additionally_ since .NET Framework 4.6.1 (and .NET Core 1). There was no .NET version specified in the question, so I assumed the current version (.NET Framework 4.8 or .NET Core 3.1).

Comment: my mistake, I should have mentioned the version.

Answer (score 1):

I generated the key as suggested by @Topaco  and used it with JwtSecurityTokenHandler of identity model and it worked.
the function which i was trying to use in question did not work for some reasons:
The working code is as follows:

```
public static bool ValidateEcdsa512JwtToken(string token, string publicKey)
{
    ECDsa pubKey = LoadPublicKey(publicKey);

    var securityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        IssuerSigningKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(pubKey)
    };

    SecurityToken stoken;
    var claims = securityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out stoken);
    var verified=claims.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

    return verified;
}


private static ECDsa LoadPublicKey(string publicKey)
{
     byte[] publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey);
     var keyType = new byte[] { 0x45, 0x43, 0x53, 0x35 };
     var keyLength = new byte[] { 0x42, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
     var key = keyType.Concat(keyLength).Concat(publicKeyBytes.Skip(publicKeyBytes.Length - 132)).ToArray();

     CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Import(key, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
     ECDsaCng eCDsaCng = new ECDsaCng(cngKey);
     eCDsaCng.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP521;
     return eCDsaCng;
}
```