# verify signature of JWT Token c#

Tags: c#, jwt, base64, signature, verify

I have some problems to verify the signature of a JWT token I get. The token is signed with HS256. The code where I try to create a signature to proof the received one is:

```
JwtSecurityToken token = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(tokenString);

byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret");

HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes);
byte[] signatureBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token.RawHeader + "." + token.RawPayload));
string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
```

The signature I get from the received token is for example:

```
pYscLlinuNhO-sFyEIRRLZP7yrl8GopGJ3I6QSxg2tU
```

But the signature I get from my algorithm is in this case:

```
pYscLlinuNhO+sFyEIRRLZP7yrl8GopGJ3I6QSxg2tU=
```

So the signatures are close, but not equal. I don't get what I'm doing wrong at the verification of the signature. Letters and numbers seems to be correct every time but special characters are mostly different and there is always a '=' at the end of the signature.
Maybe someone knows what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three parts of a JWT are [Base64Url encoded](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-3):

> A JWT is represented as a sequence of URL-safe parts separated by
> period ('.') characters.  Each part contains a base64url-encoded
> value.

But you used [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. Base64Url uses '-' and '_' instead of '+' and '/' and also omits the padding '=' on the end.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353710/how-to-achieve-base64-url-safe-encoding-in-c/26354677#26354677) how to convert the base64 to bas64url encoding in C#

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I tried it with Base64Url and it worked.