# Decrypt and verify hash for SHA256 - c#

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, sha256, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I am trying to decrypt and validate the hash but at times of decrypting, it throws me the error '**Key does not exist**' and at the time of validating the hash return **False**

https://payvyne.readme.io/docs/webhooks

Signature:

> 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

Public key:

> pA6ULfXWrIMq-qvxn_0CykoStq0ZMYm63lHsuXTsE4q4tgekLJDW2Lnf35ilbFU_vybBdyeJAphpsYc4P0eJBt_z2T62HAV3gnwp_GU6hWIo8faK31TSXIrLmGjZlAVynAxjFYZoNxMeZuwEXpxG4bRGs58P7XSx1fAzedX6oGIlcSLljKH4I1BHt6gJhPIHYNXQzq_a0hX54C1m1VDVP_kot8ui1YKZil_riROK_Xk4ktnOTAqXo9z4uNBqzzH2k0J2YNiCb8VOdbp7kjmH9sPLI-jb-ociy0wSkGZc1e8saGIkkSm4eUASvX_M_TTDD99OrgoIS2Vx07Tw4lK5yd28EMVBUzy2OypuPVf9PyoDGv_4241x5PpJsA9IKocD7AgwxJ3E7FBFhvuSP8c5wspkbQxBwv5nnk2zAxuZsiJeK0o3JSxjkZJEkeVY4mA3VV9SvSXEKAFg2h9J3CR9PTwrZoVBruycVtWJ4it5jroXff-aGlLoRAO0g3gtfjkJb3tw6SJTFOA49iJci76Mj8Adz3eeEEGxTxfDzh_lq0jXxTk7cQSaR2_ChYLHaoorrrFmAvWgDH_lSvlISIgey-SzUoJM9RAy4gVFdmg-XCQQlpMh_d1-IACO3EfBvYKWE-6uGIqx1nZhn9WIDdSqMp6940xRxl0vQy8vYCQ5q8U

Data for Sign in string:

> {"type":"PAYMENT_STATUS_CHANGE","paymentId":"1c6e834f074ec941","status":"FAILED","timestamp":1652688286662,"amount":"164.69","currency":"GBP","description":"This is test payment","paymentType":"ONE_OFF","bankName":"Diamond bank","destinationAccount":"GBP2","createdAt":"2022-05-16T08:04:32.994","updatedAt":"2022-05-16T08:04:46.662","customerReference":"1199","refundedAmount":"0.00"}

Expo (exponent):

> AQAB

Below is the code to Decrypt the signature using public key.

```
public static void DecryptUsingPublicKey(string publicKey, string expo, string signature)
{
    var modulus = ConvertToBase64(publicKey);
    var exponent = Convert.FromBase64String(expo);

    RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
    var _publicKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);

    _publicKey.Modulus = modulus;
    _publicKey.Exponent = exponent;
    csp.ImportParameters(_publicKey);

    var dataBytes = ConvertToBase64(signature);
    var plainText = csp.Decrypt(dataBytes, false);
    var returnData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText);
    Console.WriteLine($"value: {returnData}");
}
```

Below is the code for Verify signature using public key

```
public static void VerifySignature(string signature, string pKey, string dataForSign)
{
    string pKeyNew = pKey;
    pKeyNew = pKeyNew.Replace("_", "/").Replace("-", "+");
    string publicKey = $"<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>{pKeyNew}==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";

    var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] dataForSignAsBytes = encoder.GetBytes(dataForSign);

    byte[] signatureAsBytes = ConvertToBase64(signature);

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(publicKey);

    var hashData = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(dataForSignAsBytes);

    var result1 = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData(dataForSignAsBytes, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signatureAsBytes);
    var result2 = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.VerifyHash(hashData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signatureAsBytes);
    var result3 = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.VerifyHash(hashData, signatureAsBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    var result4 = rsaCryptoServiceProvider.VerifyData(dataForSignAsBytes, signatureAsBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
    Console.WriteLine(result1);
    Console.WriteLine(result2);
    Console.WriteLine(result3);
    Console.WriteLine(result4);
}
```

**ConvertToBase64** function

```
public static byte[] ConvertToBase64(string data)
{
    byte[] cyperBuffer;
    string dataNew = data;
    dataNew = dataNew.Replace("_", "/").Replace("-", "+");
    try
    {
        if (dataNew.Substring(dataNew.Length - 1) != "=")
        {
            dataNew += "=";
        }
        cyperBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(dataNew);
    }
    catch
    {
        dataNew += "=";

        try
        {
            cyperBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(dataNew);
        }
        catch
        {
            //If any error occured while convert to base64 then append '=' at the end.
            dataNew += "=";
            cyperBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(dataNew);
        }
    }

    return cyperBuffer;
}
```

Comment: For decryption, the private key is required.

Comment: Regarding verification: There is a bug in `publicKey`. `pKey` is Base64url decoded 512 bytes large. Thus, Base64 encoded it must not be padded with *two* padding bytes, but only *one*. Btw, instead of the static `==`, a more generic solution makes more sense, e.g. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26354677/9014097). If this is fixed and - as already identified in the answer - the signature is Base64 decoded with `Convert.FromBase64String(signature)`, verification with all four variants is successful.

Comment: I strongly suspect a copy paste error for the `publicKey`, but OK, make that 2 conversion errors :P Note that I think the whole idea of outputting bytes for base 64 *encoding* is a mistake in itself; just outputing characters or a text string makes much more sense (even though the standard often describes it as a byte-to-byte/ASCII encoding as well).

Comment: Hi @Topaco,  We are getting the public key in JSON Web Algorithms like, https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-6.3.1.1.

Comment: With your implementation of `ConvertToBase64()` the verification is successful if you replace `{pKeyNew}==` with `{pKeyNew}=`! Regarding `ConvertToBase64()`: The name is poor, because in the end a Base64url/Base64 decoding takes place (exactly the opposite of what the name suggests). The equally poor implementation works for your key, but not in general. My recommendation: For the conversion of the key from Base64url to Base64 use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26354677/9014097 and Base64 decode the signature with `Convert.FromBase64String(signature)`.

Comment: S. online on .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TEDBHY.

Comment: Hey @Topaco, Thanks for the help in verifying the signature but I still faced the issue in decrypt the signature. Please let me know if you may have an idea.  it throws the error **Key does not exist**

Comment: I' ve posted an executable code on .NET Fiddle. Just compare your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a conversion mistake; you need to **decode** the base 64 signature, not encode the signature, so the following line is wrong:

```
byte[] signatureAsBytes = ConvertToBase64(signature);
```

it should be something like:

```
byte[] signatureAsBytes = ConvertFromBase64(signature);
```

---

Decryption is modular exponentiation with a private key. Furthermore, encryption normally uses a different padding scheme than signature generation, so you'd expect that the unpadding would fail if you try and decrypt. Only verification is possible.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your suggestion, I forgot to put my ConvertToBase64 function.

Comment: That's a rather generic function for base64url decoding, please don't code that yourself. Try again with one provided by a library, or at least write some unit tests. How performant do *you* think those replacement statements are? And you only seem to add *one* `=` character at max. They should be added until the base 64 characters are a multiple of 4 - that's why padding characters exist.