# Getting System.FormatException: while reading "n" and "e" records from jwk file hosted on a server

Tags: c#, .net-core, base64, jwk

I am trying to verify the JWT signature using a JWK file hosted on a server.

I have a jwk model in my project Jwk which looks like below:

```
public class Jwk{
        [JsonProperty("alg")]
        public string Alg { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("e")]
        public string E { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("kty")]
        public string Kty { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("n")]
        public string N { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("use")]
        public string Use { get; set; }
}
```

here how I am using it in a code:

```
public TokenValidationParameters VerifyToken(Jwk jwk)
        {
            // Here I am getting the exception
            RSAParameters rsaParams = new RSAParameters
            {
                Modulus = Convert.FromBase64String(jwk.N),
                Exponent = Convert.FromBase64String(jwk.E),
                
            };

            using RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);

            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa)
            };

            return validationParameters;
        }
```

I am getting the exception saying:

```
System.FormatException: 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.'
```

My data looks like this:

```
{ 
    "kty": "RSA", 
    "n": "qum6HexDv55WPr9iqoO-yOoqGRiFaF0Vx7YAigPYsLdyAgnmQRKxI81_XgJfH_f18mNO_j4GCVLIzvQYZGFw9cIs3b3kt9frxNssc24_Uh6zccvE2XWn9yr81OYu85OfL4mgA1WQPm- 
ZKIzvPq77ISY51PBSpK6FQkwuc9OhWDk",
    "e": "AQAB", 
    "alg": "RS256", 
    "use": "sig" 
}
```

Comment: Your Class `Jwk` properties `N` & `E` accept any string, this could mean that `N` is not a valid base64 string (as highlighted by the error). Try to attach the debugger on the code To see if the properties have a value. I assume that either the value passed is not a valid base64 string or is empty

Comment: Yes, its reading a properties and all properties contain expected values

Comment: Key parameters like modulus and exponent are Base64**url** encoded in a JWK (i.e. do not apply the *standard* Base64 encoding). So try if it works with a Base64url decoding. For Base64url with C# s. e.g. [*How to achieve Base64 URL safe encoding in C#?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26353710/9014097).

Comment: Presumably what you expect isn't what the Framework expects here. Without seeing whats in those properties we can't really help.

Comment: ```
{
  "kty": "RSA",
  "n": "qum6HexDv55WPr9iqoO-yOoqGRiFaF0Vx7YAigPYsLdyAgnmQRKxI81_XgJfH_f18mNO_j4GCVLIzvQYZGFw9cIs3b3kt9frxNssc24_Uh6zccvE2XWn9yr81OYu85OfL4mgA1WQPm-ZKIzvPq77ISY51PBSpK6FQkwuc9OhWDk",
  "e": "AQAB",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "use": "sig"
}
```

this a sample data I am using

Comment: Yeah the underscores are not "standard" base64, that's base64url encoded.