# Error Decrypting AES Encrypted Data in .NET C#: Invalid Base-64 String Issue

Tags: c#, .net, angular, encryption

I am facing an issue with decrypting AES encrypted data in my .NET C# application. I am encrypting a JSON object in Angular using the CryptoJS library and attempting to decrypt it in C# using the `RijndaelManaged` class. When I try to decrypt the data in C#, I encounter the following error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters

Here is my encryption code in Angular:

```
const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('4512631236589784');
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('4512631236589784');
const data = {id: 1, name: "test"};
const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), key, {
    keySize: 128 / 8,
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
console.log('Encrypted : ' + encrypted);
```

And here is my decryption code in C#:

```
public string DecryptData()
{
    try
    {
        var token = HttpContext.Request.Query["token"];
        var keybytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("4512631236589784");
        var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("4512631236589784");

        var encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(token);
        var decryptedFromJavascript = DecryptStringFromBytes(encrypted, keybytes, iv);
        return decryptedFromJavascript;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return e.Message;
    }
}

    private string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        }

        if (key == null || key.Length <= 0) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        }

        if (iv == null || iv.Length <= 0) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        }

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an RijndaelManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (var rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())  
        {
            //Settings
            rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            rijAlg.FeedbackSize = 128;

            rijAlg.Key = key;
            rijAlg.IV = iv;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            var decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            try 
            {
                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using(var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText)) 
                {
                    using(var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) 
                    {
                        using(var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt)) 
                        {
                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch 
            {
                plaintext = "keyError";
            }
        }

        return plaintext;
    }
```

The strange thing is that this issue occurs only when the encrypted data is larger, such as when I encrypt a JSON object. When I encrypt smaller text like "welcome", it works fine. I have verified that the `key` and `IV` are the same on both sides. I suspect it might be an issue related to encoding, transmission, or padding, but I can't pinpoint the exact problem.

For example, when I pass:

```
const data = { id: 1, name: "test" };
```

and encrypt it, I get the following result:

```
+IhryRiKnNFiOWNv3cnWde97CiTZZLtVPMbnIm5ieDg=
```

Similarly, when I encrypt the word `hello`:

I got the output

```
v8FQU3S6MnFlkSK349fZUQ==
```

Any help or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Well we don't know the value of `token`, which is the value that's causing the problem... That makes it hard to help you. Perhaps this is web-safe base64?

Comment: @JonSkeet Question updated, check now.

Comment: The CryptoJS code returns `+IhryRiKnNFiOWNv3cnWdW46Iz5idrstgKYklA6y110=`, so not what you posted (note the missing `=` at the end). What you posted may be what arrives on the C# side. As suspected in the first comment, probably a Base64url encoding is missing. Try on the CryptoJS side `encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64url)`. On the C# side you have to decode with Base64url, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26354677).

Comment: I received this value with CryptoJS: `+IhryRiKnNFiOWNv3cnWde97CiTZZLtVPMbnIm5ieDg=`, but on the C# side, I encountered a Base64 decode error

Comment: I see the issue now. When I directly pass the value `+IhryRiKnNFiOWNv3cnWde97CiTZZLtVPMbnIm5ieDg` as a variable, it works fine. However, when I try to pass it in a URL query as token, I encounter an error.

Comment: Your data is inconsistent: `{"id":1,"name":"test"}` returns `+IhryRiKnNFiOWNv3cnWdW46Iz5idrstgKYklA6y110=` (i.e. the ciphertext you originally posted), while to generate `+IhryRiKnNFiOWNv3cnWde97CiTZZLtVPMbnIm5ieDg=` the plaintext `{"id":1, "name": "himanshu"}` was applied. Post consistent data!

Comment: And the cause of the problem plus a possible solution have already been addressed: Try Base64url instead of standard Base64.

Comment: You still haven't told us the value of `token`. You've told us what you received from CryptoJS - but not what value you're getting from `HttpContext.Request.Query["token"]`

Comment: token value would be encrypted data from Angular and passed to .NET.

Answer (score -1):

The error message “The input is not a valid base-64 string” indicates that there is a problem with the data you are trying to decrypt in your C# application. This problem usually occurs when the data format does not match or there are unexpected characters in the encrypted data.

Comment: Question updated, check now