# Message parsing with Mimekit Parsing Gmail API is always empty

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api, mime, mimekit

I am making a call to the Gmail API endpoint: `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/[id]` to get an email message (where `[id]` is the ID of the message I am getting).

I know that my OAuth and API call are working, as I can successfully display the basic email info (subject, snippet, etc) in my app. I am struggling to parse the MIME data for the body, however.

I am using [MimeKit](http://www.mimekit.net/), and have reviewed and implemented the documentation for [parsing messages](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Parsing-Messages.htm). My code looks something like this:

```
public static string ParseMessage(string content)
{
    // 'content' contains the json returned from the Gmail API call.
    JsonNode jsonObject = JsonNode.Parse(content);

    // ... parsing other stuff here that works ...

    // Parsing the MIME content that does NOT work...
    string payload = jsonObject["payload"].ToJsonString();
    string body = ParseMime(payload);

    // ... other stuff ...
}

public static string ParseMime(string content)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content));
    MimeMessage message = MimeMessage.Load(stream);

    // Implementation from 'Working with Messages' goes here ...
    // http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Working-With-Messages.htm
}
```

I have attempted to implement each of the three strategies from the [Working with Messages](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Working-With-Messages.htm) page of the documentation, but none of them are working as expected. Inspecting the data structures in `MimeMessage`, I find them empty. This leads me to believe the content isn't being parsed correctly.

1. **Am I putting in the correct content to be parsed by the `MimeMessage.Load()` function?** Based on the [API method documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) and the [response REST resource documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#header), I believe the json object in the `payload` property of the response is what is needed (the root of the MIME part tree).
2. **Is there some other encoding/decoding or other preparation step I am missing before attempting to parse the MIME content in the message?**

The response I receive from the Gmail API, for reference, looks like this (data values are not blank in the actual response, but are removed here for privacy):

```
{
    "id": "",
    "threadId": "",
    "labelIds": [],
    "snippit": "",
    "payload": {
        "partId": "",
        "mimeType": "",
        "filename": "",
        "headers": [],
        "body": {},
        "parts": []

    },
    "sizeEstimate": ###,
    "historyId": "",
    "internalDate": ""
}
```

Comment: What happens if you request the endpoint with the same query in say Postman?

Comment: I am using Postman as well to compare and verify the API call is working. The response I get in Postman matches exactly what I get in the app; it is the same json response that I am parsing in `ParseMessage()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "payload" attribute in the sample JSON that you pasted doesn't contain a MIME message, it contains a JSON dictionary which isn't something that MimeKit can parse.

You need to find a way to get the raw MIME message data.

Based on what I can tell from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get), you need to specify that the `format` you want is `raw`, and then the response will contain a `raw` attribute that will be the base64 encoded MIME data.

SO it sounds like you'd get this:

```
{
    "id": "",
    "threadId": "",
    "labelIds": [],
    "snippit": "",
    "raw": "<URL-safe base64 encoded raw MIME data goes here>",
    "sizeEstimate": ###,
    "historyId": "",
    "internalDate": ""
}
```

Then your code would need to change to this:

```
// Parsing the MIME content
string payload = jsonObject["raw"].GetValue<string>();
string body = ParseMime(payload.Replace(‘_’, ‘/‘).Replace(‘-‘, ‘+’));
```

And ParseMime() would need to be changed to this:

```
public static string ParseMime(string base64)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64), false);
    MimeMessage message = MimeMessage.Load(stream);

    // Implementation from 'Working with Messages' goes here ...
    // http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Working-With-Messages.htm
}
```

Comment: This was almost exactly what I needed! Just two minor changes. First, I actually needed to use `jsonObject["raw"]!.GetValue<string>();`, because `ToJsonString()` includes quotation marks in the message. Second, I needed to do one more step. The raw format from the Google API is not directly Base64, it is URL-safe Base 64. I needed to add the step `payload.Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+');` (see solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353710/how-to-achieve-base64-url-safe-encoding-in-c). Can you update the answer and I will make it as the answer?

Comment: I’ve just updated my answer