# convert java aes encryption to c# .net

Tags: java, c#, .net, encryption, aes

I have java library which will do encryption using AES, which we need to convert to C#.NET.
Here is my java code:

```
public static String encryptAES(String plain, String secretKey, String iv) throws Exception {
        return encrypt(plain, secretKey, iv, "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING", "AES");
    }
 
     private static String encrypt(String plain, String secretKey, String iv, String algorithm, String secretKeyAlgorithm) throws Exception {
        var cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        var secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), secretKeyAlgorithm);
        var ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, ivParameterSpec);
 
        var cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());
        return Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Here is my code in c#:

```
public static string AesEncryption(string plainText, string key, string iv)
        {
            byte[] encrypted;
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
                aesAlg.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iv);
                aesAlg.BlockSize = 128;
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                // Create the streams used for encryption. 
                using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {                         
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                        var evncrypted = System.Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
                        return evncrypted;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm looking for both my java and .net functions should give me same result

using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())

Comment: The line `aesAlg.BlockSize = 128` triggers the generation of a new random IV. Remove the line, it is not necessary as the block size of AES is 128 bits by definition! In addition, the ciphertext must be Base64url (and not Base64) encoded to be compatible with the Java code, see [How to achieve Base64 URL safe encoding in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26353710/9014097).